# Updating mongodb data without deleting the old

Tags: node.js, mongodb, architecture

I want to update my data in my mongodb cluster without deleting the old data, because in my current project I need my old data to put it in a table on the client side.

Comment: The question is a little vague. Kindly include code samples

Comment: may be google for a tutorial?